# GCM - multiple notifications

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Google Cloud Messaging (one way only, i.e. server to client) to receive Push-notifications.
I am receiving these, and at first everything was fine, but now, after a bit over a week, I get multiple notifications; 3 on one device, and 7 on the other.

My theory is that the devices register with different ids, and thus get multiple notifications.

But why can that be? I am using Googles sample Android project, adapted it to mine, but can't see what would cause these multiple registrations. 
Is it because the registration ids have expired?

**EDIT: All registrationIds on the sever are different however.**

**EDIT2: I think I called GCMRegistrar(context) in the onDestroy()-method of the activity, but didn't actually unregister the registration id on my server. Might that be the problem? What does it mean if the registration id is unregistered?**

Comment: Where are you storing your registered devices IDs?

Comment: They are stored on the server (which I didn't implement). Does the server have to check if the registration id has expired?

Comment: does the server check if the ID has already been stored? sounds like you are sending it out multiple times due to it being stored multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reflecting on your latest comment
(The GCM engine might change the registration ID whenever it determines it need to, and this might happen at anytime without prior warning, that's why you should always check if the last registration ID matches the one that is current), I have this solution:

1. Have webservice function like registerDevice(GCM_ID,DeviceID)
2. Now from DB fetch the GCMIdColumn where DeviceIDColumn = DeviceID. If this GCMIdColumn != GCM_ID, then update. Else do nothing.
3. If there is no row with having DeviceIDColumn = DeviceID, then insert (GCM_ID,DeviceID).

DeviceID: A ID picked up from the App.
GCM_ID: Id returned by GCM.

Now the only thing you must be certain about is that  DeviceID you generate from the app should be unique. You can combine 2 or more properties of the device's configuration to make it unique.

**Generate Device ID**

```
public String getDeviceID(Context context) {
        TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String szImei = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId(); // Requires READ_PHONE_STATE
        String m_szDevIDShort = "35" + //we make this look like a valid IMEI
                Build.BOARD.length()%10+ Build.BRAND.length()%10 +
                Build.CPU_ABI.length()%10 + Build.DEVICE.length()%10 +
                Build.DISPLAY.length()%10 + Build.HOST.length()%10 +
                Build.ID.length()%10 + Build.MANUFACTURER.length()%10 +
                Build.MODEL.length()%10 + Build.PRODUCT.length()%10 +
                Build.TAGS.length()%10 + Build.TYPE.length()%10 +
                Build.USER.length()%10 ; //13 digits
        if(Utills.debug)
            Log.i("getDeviceID",szImei+"==XXX=="+m_szDevIDShort);
        return szImei+"==XXX=="+m_szDevIDShort;
    }
```

Hope this is the solution you are looking for!

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, any ideas on  how to create a custom unique id for one device? Maybe using the IMEI?

Comment: @deimos1988 Please see the updated answer. This is a snippet I used in one of my projects. You can update/modify it suit your need.

Comment: Thank you for your code, I read that there might be a  problem with that (apart from possible privacy issues), so I decided to use a hash-value of the MAC-address of the wlan-module as a unique id.

Comment: I will, as soon as it is implemented at the server and I can test it :)

Comment: Sorry if I sounded like a Repo Hungry Freak 
go ahead take your time!!

Comment: Dr. It's ok, no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Even without having seen your code, I guess the problem is the following:

The server is not checking whether a registered device is already registered in the database and thus you're having duplicated entries, therefore you're sending the same notification several times to the same client.

Even doing this, you *need* to implement a timeout policy. In my projects, I have a `Thread` that every X time sends a dummy HTTP request to the third-party server, so if a device fails to send it after a reasonable amount of time, it's a timeout and I remove it from the database.

I guess solving these 2 issues will solve your problem.

Comment: All registrationIds are different however.

Comment: Then the issue has to be in the script that sends `GCM` messages, or in the code that processes the received message. Either one of these three. There's no other possibility.

Comment: So I don't need to worry about registrationIds expiring?

Comment: Having a device registered multiple times on your backend is the causing this malfunction, as pointed out in this answer. May be you are into developing phase, so you must have uninstalled and re-installed the app multiple times on your test devices, which is causing this. You can simply have a Boolean variable to recognize if you have already registered a device with GCM.

Comment: Yes, you should. Your database will contain all the supposedly `active` IDs, you should implement some mechanism to make this up-to-date (a way would be the one I described). Otherwise you could be sending notifications to devices that are not registered, and also to devices that have changed their IDs (Google may sometimes change the ID that assigns to a device from time to time)

Comment: @Eu.Dr. I reinstalled the app several times - if you think that this might be the reason for the behaviour, how exactly do I check if the device has already registered? The Boolean value will be lost after the app has been reinstalled?

Comment: @nKn By "my database" you mean the database on the client, or on the server? 
How can my server know if Google changed the registration id?

Comment: I mean the server side. You cannot know it, just implement a timeout mechanism and you won't have to deal with it, as each time you run your ap you should register against the `GCM` server and afterwards send the ID to the remote server as a an active `ID` that wants to receive notifications. Aditionally, you should unregister the device from `GCM` and your remote server each time the app closes/exits.

Comment: @nKn unregistering from GCM when you app closes is not a goood idea as you wont get the push if you background your app, http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg

Comment: @nKn Okay, but unfortunately I still don't quite get how the timeout mechanism would be implemented, and what exactly it would achieve? Please also check my EDIT2 of my original question.

Comment: To implement a timeout mechanism, start a `Handler` in your main `Activity` by calling `.postDelayed(this, 30000)`, for instance. As the implementation, just make a `HTTP POST` query sending your `GCM` id and another field that it would recognize it as the `keepalive` (for instance, you can call it like this). This way, you'll have to change your database to have one more column called for instance `last_keepalive` of type `TIMESTAMP`, so each time a client updates, you update this field knowing its `ID`. Then you'll have to have a `cron`-like tool that would be fired say every 2-3 minutes

Comment: and delete all those clients in your database that would have a `last_keepalive` value for more than, say, 10 minutes. This is how I implemented mine and works perfectly as a timeout mechanism.

Comment: @deimos1988 Whenever you register with GCM from the app, a unique ID is produced for every GCM APP ID and DEVICE ID, no matter how many times you register, it will always be the same GCM_REGISTERATION_ID that you will get. It is not possible to check from the App weather it has already been registered. However, you can easily add this logic to your backend. Just add a constraint UNIQUE to the column GCM_REG_ID in your table definition.

Comment: @Eu.Dr. Ok, thank you for the explanation. I just checked, and my device has a different registration Id today than it had yesterday. How is that possible? I changed some stuff in my app, but nothing GCM-specific.

Comment: The `GCM` engine might change the registration `ID` whenever it determines it need to, and this might happen at anytime without prior warning, that's why you should **always** check if the last registration ID matches the one that is current.

Comment: @nKn Okay, I can check within the app whether the registration id has been refreshed or not. But even when I determine that the id has changed, I cannot do anything client-side, only on my server, or can I?

Comment: @deimos1988 please check the answer I posted, may be it can help you out.

Comment: No, you just send the `ID` to the server and it will handle it accordingly. Plus if you implement the timeout mechanism, you should not have any trouble with registration ID duplicates or inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct solution/fix to your answer but `GCMRegistrar(context)` have been deprecated for a while now. I would stay away from it as it is not recommended to use.

> package com.google.android.gcm **DEPRECATED** — please use the
>   [GoogleCloudMessaging](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html) API instead of this client helper library — see
>   GCM Client for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably its sent multiple times from server side

Comment: This seems answer to me, it might that this user has guessed wrong but of course this is answer

Comment: GCM - multiple notifications because `Most probably its sent multiple times from server side` ?